# Function and variable assignment in conditional ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to write a conditional `ng-click` with a function call and assignment. It's really important for me that this assignment is not written within a function because that function is quite generic.

I have 2 conditions I need to fulfil in order for ng-click function and assignment to be executed.

Here are some variations I have tried so far

```html
<button ng-click="vm.hasPermission && vm.readOnly === false
                    ? vm.myFunction(); vm.buttonTouched = true
                    : null">
  My Button
</button>

<!-- As suggested in other stackoverflow thread (doesn't work) -->
<button ng-click="vm.hasPermission && vm.readOnly === false
                    ? (vm.myFunction(), vm.buttonTouched = true)
                    : null">
  My Button
</button>

<button ng-click="vm.hasPermission && vm.readOnly === false
                    ? vm.myFunction() && vm.buttonTouched = true
                    : null">
  My Button
</button>
```

The key bit is that I don't want `vm.buttonTouched = true` in `vm.myFunction()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about trying the following:

```html
<button ng-click="vm.hasPermission && (vm.readOnly === false) && (vm.buttonTouched = true) && vm.myFunction()">
  My Button
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the button within an `ng-if` statement when you want the function called with the assignment? For example something like:

```html
<button ng-if="vm.hasPermission && !vm.readOnly" ng-click="vm.myFunction(); vm.buttonTouched = true;"> My button </button>

<button ng-if="!vm.hasPermission || vm.readOnly" ng-click="do whatever you want here"> My button </button>
```